# how can I add an event to a nodelist object

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

okay so I am trying to use a `addEventListener` method to make a click `event` that will toggle a class to animate my menu bar and have a side menu appear. This is my code

```js
//reference to the ".menu" class
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
console.log(menu)

const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menu-button')
// Using your menuButton reference, add a click handler that calls toggleMenu
console.log(menuButton);
menuButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  menuButton.classList.toggle('.menu--open');
  console.log('toggled');
});
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="menu-button" src="./assets/menu.png" />
  <h1>Lambda School Newsfeed</h1>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Students</li>
    <li>Faculty</li>
    <li>What's New</li>
    <li>Tech Trends</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li>Log Out</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I get that I am getting a nodelist in return and does not allow me to use the event method, but I can't seem to solve the problem

Comment: You don't have any nodeLists here, only singular elements..? If you want the `event` object, declare it as a parameter to the listener function? See snippet, your code looks to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.` from `.menu--open` in this snippet `menuButton.classList.toggle('.menu--open');`

```js
//reference to the ".menu" class
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
console.log(menu)

const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menu-button')
// Using your menuButton reference, add a click handler that calls toggleMenu
console.log(menuButton);
menuButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  menuButton.classList.toggle('menu--open');
});
```

```css
.menu--open {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="menu-button" src="./assets/menu.png" />
  <h1>Lambda School Newsfeed</h1>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Students</li>
    <li>Faculty</li>
    <li>What's New</li>
    <li>Tech Trends</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li>Log Out</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. You need to use `menu--open` instead of `.menu--open` inside the class list toggle function
2. You need to use `menu.classList.toggle` instead of `menuButton.classList.toggle`

```js
//reference to the ".menu" class
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
console.log(menu)

const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menu-button')
// Using your menuButton reference, add a click handler that calls toggleMenu
console.log(menuButton);
menuButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  menu.classList.toggle('menu-open');
});
```

```css
.menu.menu-open {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="menu-button" src="./assets/menu.png" />
  <h1>Lambda School Newsfeed</h1>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Students</li>
    <li>Faculty</li>
    <li>What's New</li>
    <li>Tech Trends</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li>Log Out</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```